# Using Mercurial repository copies to recover lost SVN commits

Tags: svn, mercurial

I made a few Mercurial repositories by cloning individual folders from a large SVN repository. There was some data loss to the SVN repository and now these Mercurial clones are the only backup I have. Initially I thought I could just push them back to the SVN repository but I get the message `no changes found` for some folders and `Could not push revision 864204e88250 because it had no changes in svn` for at least one other.

Is there any feasible way to recover the SVN repository, or is my best bet to add new commits using the old messages/files (to preserve the log history, at least)?